# Application temporarily freezes after switching Wi-Fi ON

Tags: windows, qml, c++17, qt5

I am developing a QML (Qt5.15.2) desktop application that is primarily aimed at Windows 10 users.

I have the strangest of bugs that I cannot think of a way to debug, this is kind of a bottle in the sea.

There are some actions that lead to a QML `Loader` having to load a "big" section of the UI (ex: creating a new tab in the application). These operations are always smooth and does not impact performance in any ways.

But, if I switch the Wi-Fi from OFF to ON and connect to a network, then try to open a tab, the application freezes for 10/15 seconds. This only happens the first time after the Wi-Fi is turned ON, all the other tab opening after the first one are smooth until I turn the Wi-Fi OFF then ON again and try again.

My application **does not** try to reach the internet, it is purely offline. I get the freeze whether the Wi-Fi network can reach the internet or not. And it only freezes on the first interaction after the Wi-Fi is turned ON, but it is repeatable (every time I turn OFF then ON).

The issue does not appear on wired connection. I could not reproduce the issue on Linux, it only happens on Windows, tested on Intel & Killer network interfaces.

I have no idea what to search for or a way to debug such an issue, I you have any idea on what could cause the issue, what to search for or methods to analyze the behavior it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try observing in Task Manager whether it is your app or something else that's utilizing your system for those 10-15 seconds.

Comment: Break in with the debugger during the freeze to see what your app is doing.

Comment: I saw https://blog.ando.fyi/posts/diagnosing-an-unsual-wifi-issue/ recently, but that should only result in network lag, not a freeze. Does your application have a file dialog? Perhaps it's trying to enumerate files on a network drive or something? Does it happen with Qt 6?

Comment: @Mitch You guessed right! QtQuick.Dialogs `FileDialog` causes the freeze when the property `selectFolder` is set to true and network drives are no longer reachable after a network change. Using Qt.labs.platform `FolderDialog` fixes the issue. Please create  an answer so that I can accept it
For people seeing this in the future, here is the ticket opened to try to have the issue fixed in Qt5.15.2: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-107118

Comment: Oh wait, you're using QtQuick.Dialogs 1.x. Can you try with the new FileDialog in Qt 6.2 or newer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be caused by a FileDialog, as I remember there were issues with them trying to list files on a network drive.

Comment: Adding this as a comment because I'm not sure if these are the correct bug reports. There is https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13182 for qtbase, and https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46477 and https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57832 for the old QtQuick.Dialogs 1.x module.